# GCP PubSub / Dataflow messages sent to dead letter queue even if exception is eaten in ParDo

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working with an Apache Beam pipeline in Java, which reads messages from a Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription. I've set up a ParDo function to process these messages. My expectation is that if an exception occurs during the processing of a message and is caught within the ParDo, the message should be acknowledged (since the processing reaches the end of the processElement method). However, I am observing that these messages are still being sent to a dead-letter queue (DLQ) after several delivery attempts, even though the exceptions are being caught and "eaten" (i.e., logged but not re-thrown). I've setup dead letter queue as part of my subscription setup and max delivery attempt is 5. Message ACK deadline is 60 seconds. Just an FYI that I'm experimenting with subscription dead letter queue and ideally I wouldn't eat the Exception. But this behavior is very weird.

Im doing something like this:

```
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        try {
            // Message processing logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error processing: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the Python flavor, so I am not too adept with the Java syntax. However, it looks like you still need to do something with the context. In the Python world, you still need to yield (emit) the values of the `PCollection`. In your case, I'm _guessing_ you still maybe need to `return` the `ProcessContext`. Sorry, I don't know it in Java...

Comment: You should also keep in mind that Dead Letter redirects are not supposed to be used along with Dataflow, and instead Dataflow should manage any necessary redirects: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/streaming-with-cloud-pubsub#unsupported-features